# Method of Characteristics. Steady-State Population

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on part 1 of this problem.

Suppose the human population between ages $y$ and $y + \Delta y$ is denoted $P(t,y)\Delta y$ at any time $t$, that is, $P(t,y)$ is the population density with respect to $y$. It is modeled according to the PDE
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} + D(t,y)P = 0
$$
with boundary conditions $P(t,0) = B(t)$, where $B(t)$ and $D(t,y)$ respectively represent the birth and death rates.

1. Using the method of characteristics, reduce the PDE to and ODE by making a suitable change of variables, and then find the general solution.
2. Assuming a constant birth rate $B_0$ and a time-independent death rate $D(y) = ky$ for some constant $k$, find the long-term population density $P(y)$ and the total population.

Here is what I have so far.

---

Let $\tau = t$ and $\xi = y - t$. Then, we have have some $Q(\tau, \xi) = P(t, y)$ and some $K(\tau, \xi) = D(t, y)$. Taking partial derivatives, we have

\begin{align*}
Q_t &= Q_\tau \tau_t + Q_\xi \xi_t = Q_\tau - Q_\xi\\
Q_y &= Q_\tau\tau_y + Q_\xi\xi_y = Q_\xi.
\end{align*}
Then, we have $Q_\tau = -KQ$. Separating the variables and integrating with respect to $\tau$, we have

$$
\int \frac{Q_\tau}{Q}d\tau = -\int Kd\tau.
$$
Solving out the left-hand side (leaving out the constant), we have

$$
\int \frac{Q_\tau}{Q}d\tau = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\ln{Q}d\tau = \ln{Q}.
$$

Thus, we have
$$
Q(\tau, \xi) = e^{-\int K(\tau, \xi) d\tau}.
$$

Changing variables back, we have

$$
P(t, y) = e^{-\int D(t, y) dt}.
$$

---

Is this correct so far? Are there bounds of integration on that integral? Someone told me to integrate from $0$ to $t$. That seems sort of arbitrary to me, but maybe it's a physical intuition thing. Someone else told me to instead eliminate the other variable and then have the last integral with respect to $y$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = - D(t,y)P $$

It is strange that the birth rate $B(t)$ doesn't appear in the PDE.

Of course if there is a mistake in the equation model and/or in the boundary condition, all the calculus below would be false. Nevertheless I edit it as an purely mathematical example of solving. Showing the method could help you to solve the problem by yourself in case of a corrected model and/or corrected boundary condition.

The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dP}{-D(t,y)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$y-t=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dP}{-D(t,y)} \quad\implies\quad dP+D(t,y)dt=0$
$$P+\int_0^{t} D(\tau,y)d\tau=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$P+\int_0^{t} D(\tau,y)d\tau=F(y-t)$$
$F$ is an arbitray function (until some boundary condition be taken into account).
$$\boxed{P(t,y)=-\int_0^{t} D(\tau,y)d\tau+F(y-t)}$$
BOUNDARY CONDITION : $P(t,0)=B(t)$

It is strange that a density population be equal to a birth rate. Nevertheless we continue the calculus.
$$P(t,0)=B(t)=-\int_0^{t} D(\tau,0)d\tau+F(0-t)$$
$$F(-t)=B(t)+\int_0^{t} D(\tau,0)d\tau$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is determined :
$$F(X)=B(-X)+\int_0^{-X} D(\tau,0)d\tau$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=y-t$
$$F(y-t)=B(-(y-t))+\int_0^{-(y-t)} D(\tau,0)d\tau$$
$$F(y-t)=B(t-y)+\int_0^{t-y} D(\tau,0)d\tau$$
$$P(t,y)=-\int_0^{t} D(\tau,y)d\tau+B(t-y))+\int_0^{t-y} D(\tau,0)d\tau$$
$$\boxed{P(t,y)=B(t-y)-\int_0^{t} D(\tau,y)d\tau+\int_0^{t-y} D(\tau,0)d\tau}$$
PARTICULAR CASE : $\quad\begin{cases}
B(t)=B_0=\text{constant}\\
D(t,y)=ky
\end{cases}$
$$P(t,y)=B_0-\int_0^{t} ky\,d\tau+\int_0^{t-y} 0\,d\tau$$
$$P(t,y)=B_0-kyt$$
In this case there is no steady-state. This draw to thing that something is wrong in the present wording of the problem.